# Adding tool Tips to the Spinners

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a JQuery UI Spinner Component.

```
   <input type="text" id="spinnerResolved" name="spinnerResolved"   class="spinnerTimeClass" title="Resolved Alarms Time in minutes " style="width:100px"  value="1" readonly onkeydown="curbRefreshKeysonReadonly()" ></input>
```

I want to add tooltip to the Spinner Component.

`$(".spinnerTimeClass").tooltip();`  doesnt seem to work.

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $(".spinnerTimeClass").tooltip();
    // For assigning the spinner from 1 to 60
        $( ".spinnerTimeClass" ).spinner({
                spin: function( event, ui ) {
                if ( ui.value > 60 ) {
                $( this ).spinner( "value", 1 );
                return false;
                } else if ( ui.value < 1 ) {
                $( this ).spinner( "value", 60 );
                return false;
                }
                }
        });

});
```

Comment: Works here tho http://jsfiddle.net/v8vevz6b/1/ Which plugin versions are you using?

Comment: Did you add references to jquery and jquery UI (it seems you use jquery UI tooltips)?

Comment: Yes ...i added the classes ..